# Apply Unique ID to Blog for CKEditor Comments

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, accordion

I have a Blog laid out in a Bootstrap 3 Accordion that allows the users to expand and contract the posts. Each page will display five posts with Prev and Next button at the bottom. This is working beautifully with one pesky exception.

The blog also allows comments to be displayed underneath each post as appropriate, and with those comments I have placed a CKEditor that will allow any user to add comments of their own.

Since this is an accordion, technically there are five CKEditors on the page, one for each collapsed post.  When I call for the data from the code behind, I get it like this:

```
name = Request.Form["commentname"];
email = Request.Form["comentemail"];
comment = CKEditor.InnerText;
subscribe = Request.Form["subscribecheckbox"].ToString();
currentid = Request.Form["blogid"].ToString();
```

Everything there works exactly as I need it to except the CKEditor.InnerText. It always tries to pull text from the FIRST collapsed accordion, rather than the one that actually contains the comment.

The snippet above is inside a button click event, so I do have a sender to work with.

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Is there a way to link that CKEditor's InnerText to the sender?

Here is the Comments section in the accordion:

```
<div id="commentfield" style="display: inline">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="blogid" name="blogid" style="display:none;" value="<%= Id %>" />
<p><label class="box-title" for="email">Enter your name and email. Email will NOT be shared.</label></p>
<p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="commentname" name="commentname" required placeholder="Display Name Here" /></p>
<p><input type="email" class="form-control" id="comentemail" name="comentemail" required placeholder="name@email.com" />
    <input type="email" id="commenttest" style="display:none;" name="commenttest" size="25" />
    <input type="text" id="commenttesttxt" style="display:none;" name="commenttesttxt" size="25" />
</p>
<input id="subscribecheckbox" name="subscribecheckbox" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="box-title lightblue" for="subscribecheckbox">Subscribe to Long-View Living</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="followcommentscheckbox" name="followcommentscheckbox" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="box-title lightblue" for="followcommentscheckbox">Be Notified of Followup Comments via EMail</label>
<br /><br />
<textarea runat="server" class="ckeditor" cols="20" id="CKEditor" name="CKEditor" rows="10"></textarea>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: 
Note - my solution involved switching from CKEditor to Summernote, but I do not believe that should change this solution. The same issue existed for each editor.

In my aspx, this editor is located inside a for loop. I'm looping through a DataTable that has the five blog entries in it. I'm looping on "i" so I can use that value to uniquely identify elements in each blog post.

```
int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= (myBlogDataTable.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
```

The blog posts are in this for loop, and the comments are tied to each blog that can now also be tied to the value of i.

With that in mind, I am showing the Summernote editor and my Submit Button like below, creating and identifying each object based on the value of i. This gives each of those objects a unique handle I can grab in the codebehind.

```
<% if (i == 0)
    { %>
        <br /><br />
        <textarea runat="server" id="CommentsEditor0" name="CommentsEditor0" class="summernote" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <button runat="server" id="SubmitButton0" value="0" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
<%}
    else if (i == 1)
    {%>
        <br /><br />
        <textarea runat="server" id="CommentsEditor1" name="CommentsEditor1" class="summernote" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <button runat="server" id="SubmitButton1" value="1" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
<%}
    else if (i == 2)
    {%>
        <br /><br />
        <textarea runat="server" id="CommentsEditor2" name="CommentsEditor2" class="summernote" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <button runat="server" id="SubmitButton2" value="2" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
<%}
    else if (i == 3)
    {%>
        <br /><br />
        <textarea runat="server" id="CommentsEditor3" name="CommentsEditor3" class="summernote" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <button runat="server" id="SubmitButton3" value="3" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
                <%}
    else if (i == 4)
    {%>
        <br /><br />
        <textarea runat="server" id="CommentsEditor4" name="CommentsEditor4" class="summernote" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <button runat="server" id="SubmitButton4" value="4" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
<%}%>
```

Now, in the codebehind, I can do something very similar to grab the values I want:

```
string myButtonID = ((HtmlButton)sender).Attributes["Value"].ToString();
switch (myButtonID)
{
    case "0":
        myCurrentBlogID = myStringUtility.GetField(currentid, ",", 1);
        comment = CommentsEditor0.InnerText;
        break;
    case "1":
        myCurrentBlogID = myStringUtility.GetField(currentid, ",", 2);
        comment = CommentsEditor1.InnerText;
        break;
    case "2":
        myCurrentBlogID = myStringUtility.GetField(currentid, ",", 3);
        comment = CommentsEditor2.InnerText;
        break;
    case "3":
        myCurrentBlogID = myStringUtility.GetField(currentid, ",", 4);
        comment = CommentsEditor3.InnerText;
        break;
    case "4":
        myCurrentBlogID = myStringUtility.GetField(currentid, ",", 5);
        comment = CommentsEditor4.InnerText;
        break;
}
```